# Use piped content in a python script passed as heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, python, pipe, stdin

I am aware that here-doc goes to stdin. I saw that here-doc takes precedence in going to stdin before what's coming from the pipe (see below).

But maybe there's a trick to make it work?

All in all I wanted to avoid creating a script file. I know there `-c` switch in python, but didn't want to put everything in one line neither.

```
echo values | python3 <<SCRIPT
with open('/dev/stdin') as f:
    print(f.read()) # -> "values"
SCRIPT
```

The output at the moment is the script itself:

```
with open('/dev/stdin') as f:
    print(f.read()) # -> "values"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have two stdin's - how would python know where the code stops and the content starts?

Here is a workaround by using [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
echo values | python3 <(cat <<SCRIPT
with open('/dev/stdin') as f:
    print(f.read()) # -> "values"
SCRIPT
)
```